# Can "that he is" be omitted?

Tags: meaning

> James knows is betrayed

In the example above, it seems "that he is" is omitted. Does this sentence mean "James knows that he is betrayed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence:

> James knows is betrayed

is totally not OK. You have 2 different unrelated verb with nothing to connect them. At the same time, the second clause needs its own subject, as "James" is not understood by default to be the subject.

You can re-write it as:

> James knows **he** is betrayed